# LMBD error on caffe2

Tags: python-3.x, caffe2

I am trying to learn caffe2 and I am trying to run the basic MNIST tutorial that is provided. But i am getting the following error

> enforce fail at db.h:190] db_. Cannot open db:  of type lmdb Error from operator:

I am able to download the MNIST data set both data.mdb and lock.mdb. I went through other posts related to this problem unfortunately there was not clear solution for this problem.

Can anyone please give me some pointers to solve this problem.

Thank you!

OS: Linux ubuntu 16.x
python: 3.x